# C# pass class as string and cast it from array

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types, casting

I have few nested classes like "BlueprintsManager.WorkingStandardBlueprint", and ArrayList that have instances of them. I would like to pass them to a method as a parameter, eg:

```
private void ShowBlueprints(string class_str, ArrayList class_array)
{
    // class_str would be passed as "BlueprintsManager.WorkingStandardBlueprint"
    // how here I can access class_str as a class and cast class_array to it, to access some variables.
    // for example, I need to access some BlueprintsManager.WorkingStandardBlueprint public variables.
}
```

I was messing around with Reflections, Generics but I still can't make it work.

Thank you.

Comment: So `class_str` is the name of the class, and `class_array` is what?  Is it a collection of objects, one of which (or all of which) is of the type defined by `class_str`???

Comment: yes, class_array would be a list of class instances, so if pass class_str as "BlueprintsManager.WorkingStandardBlueprint", I would like to cast class_array[0] as class_str.

Comment: what version of c# are you using

Comment: if it is 4.0 and above try this dynamic printObj=class_array[0] and access properties as printObj.property1 , you do not need to pass the class name

Comment: unfortunately it's 2.x :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use generics for this:

```
private void ShowBlueprints<T>(List<T> class_array)
{
    for (BlueprintsManager.WorkingStandardBlueprint item in class_array)
    {
        if(typeof T is BlueprintsManager.WorkingStandardBlueprint)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(((BlueprintsManager.WorkingStandardBlueprint)item).whateverpropertyyouhavedefined);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call the method like this:

```
ShowBluePrints<BlueprintsManager.WorkingStandardBlueprint>(myblueprints);
```

**EDIT** In the comments the OP says that all properties are the same. This solution would work:

```
class BaseClass
{
    string Name {get; set;}
    int id {get; set;}
}

class BlueprintsManager
{
    class WorkingStandardBlueprint : BaseClass
    {

    }
}

private void ShowBlueprints<T>(List<T> class_array) where T : BaseClass
{
    for (T item in class_array)
    {       
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is good and it works, but I have lots of these nested classes, so that was the main reason of passing string with class name, so in function I would not need to know what class I'm passing.

With your example, I would need to write if's for each class, that is what I'm trying to avoid.

Or I did not understand your answer. :-)

Comment: How would you access a property in the function if you don't know what class you have? If all properties are the same then create a base class. You could use generic constraints to make sure the method only accepts children of the base class. Are all the properties the same?

Comment: Yes, they are all the same. I need to access two variables, string name and int id.

Comment: OK, then create a baseclass and specify a constraint on your generic method. Have all your classes inherit the baseclass. I edited my answer to show you an example

Comment: That worked very very good! Thank you very much, really. I owe you a beer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is `why` more than how. I didn't see many constructs like that.

You should use generics if that satisfies what you need.

And if you really need to `construct types dynamically` from an arbitrary list of itmes

1) Make a generic method (like suggested already)

```
interface IBlueprint
{
    int ID {get;set;}
    int Name {get;set;}
}
class MyClass 
{
    private void ShowBlueprints<T>(IEnumerableT> values) where T : IBlueprint 
    {
        // access properties of IBlueprint
    }
    // I presume you 'know something' about your 'T'-s, have an interface -
    // ...if you don't you should if possible
}
```

2) And call it like this (I typed in from memory but it should be correct)

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
var values = // list of your blueprints
// if you don't have any in the list handle it and bail out
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("ShowBlueprints");
MethodInfo methodInfoGeneric = 
    methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { values.First().GetType() });
// or get your blueprint type from string if needed
methodInfoGeneric.Invoke(myclass, new object[] { values });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast an object to a type that you only know by its string name. Therefore you also cannot access its fields that way. You have some options to access the fields of a type:

1. You know the exact type (or any of its base types or interfaces), so you can cast directly:

   ```
   object first = class_array[0];
   var blueprint = (BlueprintsManager.WorkingStandardBlueprint)first;
   blueprint.MyProperty = 10;
   ```
2. You don't know the exact type but you are very sure it has a public property/field with a particular name. Note the `dynamic` keyword here, works in C# 4 and higher.

   ```
   dynamic blueprint = class_array[0];
   blueprint.MyProperty = 10;
   ```
3. You don't know the exact type, but you get a string with the type's name. And you don't know the exact property/field, but you get a string with the property's name. Then you can use reflection:

   ```
   string typeName = "BlueprintsManager.WorkingStandardBlueprint";
   string propertyName = "MyProperty";

   var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(typeName);
   var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);

   object first = class_array[0];
   // Getter:
   int result = (int)property.GetMethod.Invoke(first, null);
   // Setter
   property.SetMethod.Invoke(first, new object[] { 10 });
   ```

---

By the way, you shouldn't be using an `ArrayList`. It is a very old class from when generics didn't exist yet. Today you should use `List<T>`. For example, when you know all `T` implement an interface `IBlueprint` with the properties you want to use:

```
private void ShowBlueprints<T>(string classStr, List<T> classArray)
    where T : IBlueprint
{
    T blueprint = classArray[0];
    blueprint.MyProperty = 10;
}
```

Or if you *really* have a list of objects of any type:

```
private void ShowBlueprints(string classStr, List<object> classArray);
```

Comment: I was not able to call "GetMethod" from PropertyInfo though. I'm using mono, maybe it's missing smth.